# What are some points to be kept in mind before installing ram sticks of different sizes? (2Gb + 4Gb)

Tags: operating-systems, ramdisk, cpu-architecture, dram, memorystick

My older Desktop had a 32bit Windows 7. But since the processor was 64bit capable, I dual booted it with a 64bit Windows 7. I want to upgrade the RAM to 6Gbs by installing another 4Gb RAM stick. I would not need more than that as I only need to do some casual gaming (CSGO and stuff) on that system. I guess it will show something less than 4Gbs available in the 32bit but will show something less than 6Gbs in the 64bit OS. Or will it?

I know I need to buy a RAM with equal frequency. My current RAM is a 1333MHz so I will buy a 4Gb 1333Mhz for compatibility purpose. I will buy from the same manufacturer as well.

What are some other points that I must keep in mind before buying the new RAM stick.

Comment: I'd check the motherboard reference manuals to see what the requirements are for the slots they need to be in (assuming your MoBo even supports mixed sizes)

Comment: How do I check if my MoBo supports mixed ram sizes? Will it be written on the manual?

Comment: It should be in the manual that came with it (if you built your own PC) or you should be able to look it up online on the MoBo manufacturers website. Could you add the MoBo, manufacturer/model/revision to the question?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to crucial.com there's a memory scanner app that'll tell you what you have and what's the maximum you can add.

Nice app, but Crucial makes awful (not very reliable) RAM, so I usually go there to figure out what I need and then buy the memory from NewEgg (either Kingston or HyperX, Kingston's high-end brand).

Comment: It says my MoBo supports upto 16Gb of RAM. Although will I encounter some problems if I try to add two RAMs of same brand and frequency but of different sizes?

Comment: I nearly always add a matched set from whatever my chosen manufacturer is.  Upgrading to 8G instead of 4G wouldn't be awful, would it?